# Summing Up Using Latest Rates From A Separate Price Log - LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, razor

In an ASP Core project, with EF, have a table containing the details in respect of different types of items in inventory like:

```
public class InventoryDetails
{
    [Key, StringLength(15)]
    public string InventoryID { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(150)]
    public string InventoryName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Details { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PriceLog> PriceLogs { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SalesItem> SalesItems { get; set; }
}
```

Because of frequently changing prices of the said items, a separate price log is maintained as follows:

```
    public class PriceLog
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime PriceTime { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(15)]
    public string InventoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual InventoryDetails InventoryItems { get; set; }

    [Required, Column(TypeName = "decimal(19, 4)")]
    public decimal PricePerUnit { get; set; }

    [Required, Column(TypeName = "decimal(19, 4)")]
    public decimal TaxPerUnit { get; set; }
}
```

Similarly, Sales are being recorded in a table like the following invoices model:

```
    public class SaleInvoice
{
    [Key]
    public int SInvoiceID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime SalesTime { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SalesItem> SalesItems { get; set; }
}
```

while its items are being recorded in a separate table as:

```
    public class SalesItem
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int SInvoiceID { get; set; }

    public virtual SaleInvoice Sales { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(15)]
    public string InventoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual InventoryDetails InventoryItems { get; set; }

    [Required, Column(TypeName = "decimal(19, 4)")]
    public decimal Qty { get; set; }
}
```

Now the main objective is to show/use the **LATEST** price against each item? In other words, if the **SalesInvoice** is dated 31-Dec-2017, how to use the LATEST Sales rates of EACH item that exist (as per the Price Log table) in the year 2017 or earlier, against the Quantity (Qty) as per the SalesItem, and being **SUMMED** up at the **Invoice Level**?

For the sake of clarification, consider the following prices recorded as per Price Log like:

```
01-Dec-2017 | Strawberry | 8.59
02-Dec-2017 | Strawberry | 7.36
02-Dec-2017 | Apple      | 15.68
04-Dec-2017 | Apple      | 18.91
05-Dec-2017 | Banana     | 8.1
08-Dec-2017 | Strawberry | 7.4
09-Dec-2017 | Strawberry | 10.62
10-Dec-2017 | Orange     | 11.16
12-Dec-2017 | Apple      | 15.79
14-Dec-2017 | Strawberry | 9.57
15-Dec-2017 | Banana     | 8.34
16-Dec-2017 | Orange     | 10.37
18-Dec-2017 | Banana     | 10.07
19-Dec-2017 | Strawberry | 10.05
20-Dec-2017 | Apple      | 17.59
23-Dec-2017 | Apple      | 16.51
27-Dec-2017 | Strawberry | 10.02
30-Dec-2017 | Orange     | 10.88
04-Jan-2018 | Orange     | 12.00
06-Jan-2018 | Strawberry | 10.74
09-Jan-2018 | Apple      | 17.47
09-Jan-2018 | Banana     | 10.47
```

In this regard, this time, consider an invoice dated **5-Jan-2018**, with following items:

```
10 Strawberries
05 Apples
10 Oranges
15 Bananas
```

what would be the appropriate LINQ part to sum up the entire sales with the rates latest on the said date as:

```
27-Dec-2017 | Strawberry | 10.02 * 10 = 100.20
23-Dec-2017 | Apple      | 16.51 * 05 =  82.55
04-Jan-2018 | Orange     | 12.00 * 10 = 120.00
18-Dec-2017 | Banana     | 10.07 * 15 = 151.05
```

Thus, the Index of **SalesInvoice** reflecting the entire list of Invoices with the entry pertaining to such a date as:

```
Invoice_ID  Sales_Time  Net_Sales
....        ....        ....
....        ....        ....
0007        5-Jan-2018  453.80
....        ....        ....
....        ....        ....
```

Looking forward for you experts' help in this regard.

Thanks

Comment: Would you like to group the Pricelog by InventoryID and order in descending order by PriceTime?  (then take first to multiply with sales?)

Comment: Sure would like any of the different valuable methods available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding function to your SalesInvoice (or overloading it with a partial class).

This is not exactly LINQ query but it should get the job done.

```
public class SaleInvoice
{
    [Key]
    public int SInvoiceID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime SalesTime { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SalesItem> SalesItems { get; set; }

    /* This returns total amount for each salesitem compared to salesdate*/
    public decimal LatestRates(List<PriceLog> priceLogs)
    {
        var uniquePriceLogs = new List<PriceLog>();
        foreach (var p in priceLogs.Where(w => w.PriceTime < this.SalesTime).GroupBy(g => g.InventoryID))
        {
            var orderedLog = p.OrderByDescending(o => o.PriceTime).FirstOrDefault();
            if (orderedLog != null) uniquePriceLogs.Add(orderedLog);
        }
        decimal total = 0;
        foreach(var s in this.SalesItems)
        {
            var unique = uniquePriceLogs.FirstOrDefault(f => f.InventoryID == s.InventoryID);
            if(unique != null)
            {
                total += s.Qty * unique.PricePerUnit;
            }
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

However if I am misunderstaing your question then you could please clarify if you wanted to add to the current schema or simply create a single linq query to rule them all  :)

Comment: Sure seems to be an excellent advice, however am unaware of adding a function to a class. In this regard, how to refer to the same **LatestRates** on the Razor Page? Thanks again

Comment: First, how to access the function on the razor page depends which one the strong types you use as Model.  
Second, if you don´t have access to changing the classes then how about overloading them?  Something like "public partial class SalesInvoice" etc.

Comment: Thanks for your sincere interest in the said topic, @gardarvalur. However, have access to change the class in this regard. On the SalesInvoice model seek to have the relevant totals on the simple Index page. How to pass the argument of relevant **List** to the **LatestRates**? Something instead of the question mark in the following line of the page: <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LatestRates(?))</td>

Comment: Accordin to your classes the SalesInvoice doesn´t have any property with List of Prices, therefore we could never access it from "this" instance.  We would always need to access itt externally.  Do you have access to the PriceList within the Model in the razor view or will you need to bind it to a ViewModel instead?

Comment: I have built the LatestRates property/function as advised by you. Which property are you referring to by **PriceList**?

Comment: Sorry, I meant List of PriceLogs as stated in your InventoryDetails class.

Comment: I highly appreciate that gardavalur. No doubt the SalesInvoice class has no reference to the PriceLog directly. Any re-modelling you would recommend? Won't it create an additional joint between two tables of the database? See if you can provide a valuable suggestion of yours in this regard. Thanks again.